# Why this onSubmit not calling its function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whats wrong with this Form , when i click submit button the signInSubmitHandler() function is not called , i tested it with a simple Button with onClick and it works but if i use Form with submit button it doesnt work. (im using reactjs)

in SignInForm.jsx file:

```
    const SignInForm = (props) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Welcome to ToDo</h1>
            <form onSubmit={props.signInSubmitHandler} className={style.signInForm}>
                <div className={style.signInFormImportantElements}>
                    <span className={style.userFormsErrors}>{props.userEmailError}</span>
                    <input
                        name="userEmail"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="email"
                        value={props.currentUserEmailText}
                        className={style.signInText}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            props.signInOnChangeHandler(e);
                        }}
                        onBlur={(e) => props.signInOnBlurHandler(e)}
                    />
                    <span className={style.userFormsErrors}>{props.userPasswordError}</span>
                    <input
                        name="userPassword"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        value={props.currentUserPasswordText}
                        className={style.signInText}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            props.signInOnChangeHandler(e);
                        }}
                        onBlur={(e) => props.signInOnBlurHandler(e)}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className={style.signInSubmit} />
                </div>
                <div className={style.signInLinks}>
                    <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
                    <a href="#">Create Account</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

in app.jsx file :

```
signInSubmitHandler() {
    console.log('waaaat');
}
```

[Form Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIw1Z.png)

[props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU4OI.png)

[signInSubmitHandler binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAJEw.png)

[signInSubmitHandler function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE9R4.png)

Answer (score 0):

your function has one param

```
  signInSubmitHandler(e) {
    console.log('waaaat');

  }
```

so try this

```
  <form onSubmit={(e) => props.signInSubmitHandler(e)} className={style.signInForm}>
```

Comment: i forgot it when i was testing , i dont even need it however it doesnt work with params or without params

Comment: i faced the same issue but it resolved by a callback



onSubmit={() => props.signInSubmitHandler}

(: